# Convert column(s) data type temporally to run a new query on the temporal column data type - MySQL

Tags: mysql

This was my SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Booked_From, Booked_To FROM bookings 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,Booked_From,101) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,Booked_To,101) 
AND Hallname ='Executive Hall' 
AND Booked_From >= '11/26/2021' 
AND Booked_To <= '12/16/2021' 
AND Bin='false'  
ORDER BY str_to_date(Booked_From,'%m/%d/%Y') ASC
```

And this was the error generated:
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Booked_From,101) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,Booked_To,101) AND Hallname ='Executive...' at line 1`

Booked_From & Booked_To are VARCHARs

Comment: Looks like you try to use SQL Server syntax on MySQL. Those are different SQL engines with different SQL dialects and functions.

Comment: you are mixing sql server code with mysql

Comment: How can I achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: @Jedio in MySQL to change date format you can use date_format if is date datatype or str_to_date to vonvert string to date. If you need more dates functions check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: So many about date and time in MySQL arise because of inappropriate storage. Start by converting your `Booked_From` and `Booked_To` columns to `DATE` whereupon most of this date conversion evaporates. If you need dates in US format, do the conversion as part of the `SELECT` column list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should save dates always in MySQL in the form that is normal for MySQL yyyy-mm-dd. Because every conversion takes time

So in Mysql your query would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT Booked_From, Booked_To FROM bookings 
WHERE 
Hallname ='Executive Hall' 
AND str_to_date(Booked_From,'%m/%d/%Y') >= str_to_date('11/26/2021','%m/%d/%Y') 
AND str_to_date(Booked_To,'%m/%d/%Y')  <= str_to_date('12/16/2021','%m/%d/%Y') 
AND Bin='false'  
ORDER BY str_to_date(Booked_From,'%m/%d/%Y') ASC;
```

But it would also be better to compare dates in MySQL style

```
SELECT DISTINCT Booked_From, Booked_To FROM bookings 
WHERE 
Hallname ='Executive Hall' 
AND str_to_date(Booked_From,'%m/%d/%Y') >= '2021-11-26'
AND str_to_date(Booked_To,'%m/%d/%Y')  <= '2021-12-16'
AND Bin='false'  
ORDER BY str_to_date(Booked_From,'%m/%d/%Y') ASC
```